# How do I extract and record audio in webRTC on Firefox?

Tags: firefox, webrtc

I implemented one to one **webRTC** video chat (Both audio and video)

```
navigator.getUserMedia({
    audio: true,
    video:true
  }, function (stream) {

  }, function(err){
})
```

But i want to record only audio of the chat session. In chrome i am able to record by using [RecordRTC](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/), But in Firefox i am getting  video+audio file (webM).

How do I extract audio in Firefox from audio+video stream?

Answer (score 0):

you have one of two ways to do it, when you make new recording, you do `new RecordRTC(stream, config)`:

- currently the `stream` you are passing must be videostream, you can change it to audiostream as `stream.getAudioTracks()[0]`, I have not tried this, but guessing that it should work.
- or as part of config, add an attribute `recorderType: window.StereoRecorder`, now it would use `StereoRecorder` and not firefox's own `MediaStreamRecorder`.

p.s: have you tried recording remote stream in chrome, because chrome supports recording only stereo mode and webrtc provides audio in mono mode.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Remote stream recording not working in chrome.

Comment: yea, simplest solution for that is signalling the source browser to record the audio and upload to server/ or send directly to you using RTCDataChannel

Comment: To extract audio-only stream from Audio/Video MediaStream using Firefox [mozAV2AudioOnly](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/wiki/mozAV2AudioOnly)